# If I want to remove an ID-specified role within a function, how can I do that?

Tags: discord, discord.py

If I want to remove an ID-specified role within a function, how can I do that?

```
@bot.command()
async def aa(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    role_muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='test01')
    await member.remove_roles(role_muted)
```

What I want is to specify an ID in a function like this.

```
@bot.command()
async def aa(ctx):
    member = 414087251992117211  #ID User
    role_muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='test01')
    await member.remove_roles(role_muted)
```

how can i do it The reason I have to do this is because I will continue to develop such as When you receive this Role within 3 days if not online it will remove your Role.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Guild.get_member(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) to get a member by their ID. You can get the Guild either from the `ctx` if you want it to run in the guild where you call the command, or from a Guild ID that you store somewhere using [`Bot.get_guild(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_guild).

If you want to pass the ID in as an `argument` to the function and have it convert to a member automatically, use a [`Converter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=converter#discord-converters).

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried to do as you said. but an error occurred

Comment: You're supposed to use an **instance** of `Guild`, not literally "Guild". I said that in my answer... Use `ctx.guild` if you want to find the member in the guild you call the command from, or `bot.get_guild()` if you want to get the Guild by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example? I tried to do as you said. but an error occurred

```
@bot.command()
async def aa(ctx):
    member = discord.Guild.get_member(414087251992117211)
    role_muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='test01')
    await member.remove_roles(role_muted)
```

Error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Answer (score 0):

@UpFeR Pattamin, please comment on a reply instead of posting a new one. You're getting this error because you're not specifying which guild you are talking about. If you want to get the one that the command was executed in, I'm pretty sure you need to do `ctx.guild.get_member()`.